# Looping Through an Array in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, arrays, struct

Having a difficult time with loops and arrays in Solidity. If i have a simple contract like below (no mapping, just a struct array), is it possible to loop through the array to get a particular EntityStruct? Anyone care to show me what this might look like as far as setting up the loop is concerned?

```
contract simpleList {
     
     struct EntityStruct {
        address entityAddress;
        uint entityData;
     }
     
     EntityStruct[] public entityStructs;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple `for` loop. Like this:

```
function test() public view {
     for (uint i; i < entityStructs.length; i++) {
         address firstAddr = entityStructs[i].entityAddress;
     }
 }
```

You can manipulate the values inside the loop as you want.

Comment: Thank you for the response. One question though... does this function have to take address as an argument/input? Where do i input the address I want to look up in the array?

Comment: No it doesn't have to. It depends on what you need. If you want to *find* a specific address from the array, then you probably want to take the address as an argument, and compare it against the addresses inside the loop. Something like `if (paramAddr == entityStructs[i].entityAddress) { doSomething }`

Comment: Keep in mind that looping in smart contracts is expensive.  If you want to know something about a specific address that has been added through some function then use a mapping so you can perform a lookup in a single operation with O(1) time.  You may combine this with an array since mappings can't be iterated eg. with a for loop.